# java calculating arraylist average and getting 0 all the time

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I am writing a program of a library.
I have a class that represents a review of a book or a paper.
The review class looks like that:

```
    private String review; //a review of the book or paper
    private int reviewRate; //the rate of the review
    private String firstName; //the first name of the review writer
    private String lastName; //the last name of the review writer
    private String itemName; //the name of the book or paper
```

I also have a class of library item that represents a book or a paper and there I have a method to calculate the average of the items reviews rates and an arraylist of reviews.

```
protected ArrayList<Review> itemReviews; //array list that contains all of the reviews of the item
.
.
.
//method to calculate the average of the item reviews
    public int calculateReviewAverage ()
    {
        int average = 0; //initialize the average of the reviews rate
        int sum =0; //initialize the sum of the reviews rate
        if(itemReviews.isEmpty()) //if there are no reviews
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else //if there are reviews
        {
            for(int i=0; i<itemReviews.size(); i++) //loop through the reviews array
            {
                System.out.println(itemReviews.get(i).getReviewRate());
                sum += itemReviews.get(i).getReviewRate(); //sum all of the reviews rates
            }
            average = sum / itemReviews.size(); //calculate the average rate
            return average;
        }
    }
```

In the main I added some reviews and than call the calculateReviewAverage method and I always get 0.
This is how I added the reviews:

```
if (command.equals("makeBookReview")) {
                String readerFirstName = input.next();
                String readerLastName = input.next();
                String bookName = input.next();
                String reviewSentence = input.next();
                String rateStr = input.next();
                int rate = Integer.parseInt(rateStr);

                Reader reader = new Reader (readerFirstName, readerLastName);
                Book book = new Book(bookName); //just to find the real book

                //create review
                Review review = new Review(readerFirstName, readerLastName, bookName, reviewSentence, rate);


                if (LibrarySys.makeBookReview(book, review)) { // if adding successfully, then true returned,
                    // the following message is written to the output file
                    MyFileLogWriter.writeToFileInSeparateLine("Successfully adding book review, reader: " + reader + " to item: " + book);
                } else {
                    MyFileLogWriter.writeToFileInSeparateLine("Failed to add book review");
                }

            }
```

And the reviews are added because I printed the itemReviews array list and got this:

```
[Review [review=Pipo, reviewRate=10, firstName=Inzagi, lastName=SetTheory, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Massi, reviewRate=7, firstName=Rodregez, lastName=SetTheory, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Leo, reviewRate=8, firstName=Messi, lastName=ErdosNumber, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Leo, reviewRate=8, firstName=Messi, lastName=ErdosNumber, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Leo, reviewRate=8, firstName=Messi, lastName=integral, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Leo, reviewRate=7, firstName=Messi, lastName=DataMinig, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
[Review [review=Pipo, reviewRate=4, firstName=Inzagi, lastName=integral, itemName=great_book_to_learn_coking]]
```

What do I need to change in the code?

Comment: Is it possible that ```itemReviews``` is empty?

Comment: Can you post your main method?

Comment: There are no problems with the code you have provided.

Comment: I guess `itemReviews` must be empty post your main method how you are calling

Comment: This line should give you everything you need: `System.out.println(itemReviews.get(i).getReviewRate())`...if you don't see some lines with the `review rates` before that `0`, it means that your `for` loop was never executed, hence `itemReviews` is empty.

Comment: Is it intentional that `average` is an `int` instead of for example `double`?

Comment: did you debug the code to figure out the issue ?